# Check Date Range with a place that uses Daylight Savings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

Is there a way in Javascript to check if a location with a given long/lat and city uses Daylight Savings?

I'm currently traversing through a list of objects from different locations and need to calculate their date range in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [tz-lookup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tz-lookup) module to determine an IANA timezone from the latitude and longitude of the location, like so.

I've switched to using the [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) module to get the UTC offset in minutes for each location. Once you have this you should be able to get the difference between each city.

```js
let IANAZone = luxon.IANAZone;
let locations = [
    { lat: -33.865, lng: 151.209444, name: "Sydney"},
    { lat: 51.507222, lng: -0.1275, name: "London" },
    { lat: 42.7235, lng: -73.6931, name: "New York" },
    { lat: 39.739167, lng: -104.990278, name: "Denver"},
    { lat: 34.05, lng: -118.25, name: "Los Angeles"}
];

locations = locations.map(loc => ( { ...loc, timeZone: tzlookup(loc.lat, loc.lng) }));
   
let rows = [["Location", "Timezone", "UTC Offset (min)", "Current time"], ...locations.map(({ name, timeZone }) => [name , timeZone, IANAZone.create(timeZone).offset(new Date()) + "", new Date().toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone })])];
rows = rows.map(row => row.map(s => s.padEnd(20)).join(""))
rows.forEach(row => console.log(row))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tz-lookup@6.1.25/tz.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what does padEnd(20) do or where can I read up on this?

Comment: It will pad the string up to 20 chars, using space as.the default padding char. The docs are here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: just updated my question for the method in question I want to apply this to, would it make sense to do this:
new Date(endDate).toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone } - new Date(startDate).toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone } ?

Comment: You could do something like that. Are you looking for the range of timezones for the locations?

Comment: yeah i have different locations at different time zones so when i calculate the range, some will have an extra/less hour while others don't. I'm going to test this out rn thanks!

Comment: so turns out it doesn't work. It doesn't convert the object (only the string) :/

Comment: You could try to pass the string to the Date constructor, e.g new Date(localTimeString). Then do a getTime() and subtract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224542/discussion-between-lost9123193-and-terry-lennox).

Comment: @TerryLennox - Don't pass the string output of `toLocaleString` into the `Date` constructor.  The `Date` constructor will interpret that as *local time* - not the the time zone you intended.  Ultimately the `Date` object cannot represent other time zones.  You'll need a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

Comment: And I must say I'm impressed with Luxon, it's a nice step on from moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this question might have some useful info for you.

[How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/16086964)